# Tracing clickonce installation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I develop a .NET WPF application, that use Clickonce.

Sometimes, clickonce actualization, don't work, but I don't see any error.

I use this recommendations, but application don't generate file

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb94w1t5.aspx

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment]
"LogFilePath "="c:\\logclickonce.log"
"LogVerbosityLevel"="1"
```

Where is the log?

Comment: Can you try a different path for the log, maybe it can't write directly onto the c drive: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404265.aspx

Comment: Also see: https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/enhanced-logging-in-clickonce-deployment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File have an extra space... this work:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment]
"LogFilePath"="c:\\logclickonce.log"
"LogVerbosityLevel"="1"
```